# Using parameters in case statements in where clause SQL

Tags: sql, parameters, sql-server-2008-r2, case

I need to create a report by using ssrs but i'm having some difficulties on parameters.
I have 3 parameters, Beginning Date, Ending date and SalesID.

here is a list of what i need to do;

1-Dates can be null and if left null, all dates should be on report ( i guess a case statement is necessary here)

2- SalesID's are entered manually and can be multiple value or null. If it's null, all salesid's should come into report.

So far i tried something like this about SalesId's and dates, a piece of query is below;

```
AND ST.CREATEDDATE BETWEEN (@Baslangic) and (@Bitis)
AND CASE CPDR.SALESID   WHEN @SalesID THEN @SalesID
                        WHEN NULL THEN 'Hepsi'   END
```

(Hepsi means "All" in my native language so it's a bit of tricking SSRS in parameter selection, not sure if it would work. Other parameters are simply "beginning" and "end" as well.)

I'm getting "an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected" error on case statement, not sure what to do.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `SalesID... can be multiple value or null` : what's the parameter type of SalesID, then ? How do you pass multiple values ?

Comment: Be forewarned: "clever" logical switch constructions like this usually do not perform well in SQL code.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus multiple value thing is about the SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this I think

```
   AND XXXX = CASE CPDR.SALESID   WHEN @SalesID THEN @SalesID
   WHEN NULL THEN 'Hepsi'   END
```

What is it that's going to be put equal to @SalesID or 'Hepsi'?
You seem to be missing something infront of the case statement to compare with (hence the boolean expression error). I've added XXXX in my example.

Edit - also unless you're going to have more WHEN cases after the example, use ELSE instead of the last WHEN:

`ELSE 'Hepsi' END`

Answer (score 0):

Try smt like this:

```
AND (@Baslangic is null OR ST.CREATEDDATE BETWEEN (IsNull(@Baslangic,GETDATE())) and (isNull(@Bitis,GETDATE())))
AND (@SalesID is null OR CPDR.SALESID IN (@SalesID))
```